# Why is my static constructor called twice in an Azure Web Role?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to initialise my dependency registration for a WCF service running in an Azure Web Role, but I'm seeing a very unusual behaviour whereby the static constructor of my class is being invoked twice.

This is the `Dependencies` class I'm using as a registry point for the dependencies of the application.

```
public static class Dependencies
{
    private static IUnityContainer container;

    static Dependencies()
    {
        Dependencies.container = new UnityContainer();
    }

    public static IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }

        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public static void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // Configure container.

        Dependencies.container = container;
    }
}
```

In my overload of `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()`, I make a call to a static `ConfigureContainer` method to set up the container with my dependencies registered:

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
    // Configure container for dependency resolution.
    Dependencies.ConfigureContainer();

    return base.OnStart();
}
```

My expectation is that the static members of the `Dependencies` class should be initialised by this code and will be available to the components of the application.

What I'm seeing (using a breakpoint and the VS2012 debugger) is that the static constructor of `Dependencies` is being called twice: once during the original initialisation of the application and again during **first** request to the service. Subsequent requests don't invoke the static constructor (as expected).

I'd love to hear an explanation of why the runtime is behaving this way and what I should be doing instead to produce my static registry of dependencies.

Comment: Are you also calling ConfigureContainer in the Application_Start? And how many instances are you running?

Comment: @SandrinoDiMattia I don't have an Application_Start handler (no Global.asax) and I'm only running a single instance in my local emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely because when you host a webrole in full IIS, the RoleEntryPoint code and the rest of the web application run in different AppDomains.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2010/12/02/new-full-iis-capabilities-differences-from-hosted-web-core.aspx

Comment: I actually just stumbled across this very same article. The project template in VS2012 configured me to run under Full IIS without being clear about the difference it would cause.

Answer (score 1):

By default you use "full IIS" mode in a web role and you get two processes - IIS worker process for handling HTTP requests and role worker process for running `RoleEntryPoint` descendant code. Depending on how your code is designed you may end up using that static constructor in both processes and then it'll be invoked twice.